# pgBouncer - 2k memory optimization

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, pgbouncer

I wanted to ask if this 2k optimization made by pgBouncer and mentioned in the docs: 
Low memory requirements (2k per connection by default)

means it's the memory cost of connecting to postgres or pgBouncer?

I mean if the architecture looks like: APP -> pgBouncer -> postgres
with every element on different node is this optimization referring to the APP -> pgBouncer or  pgBouncer -> postgres connection?

Comment: This is about pgbouncer itself - meaning 1 connection to pgbouncer uses 2k of memory. Connection to PostgreSQL database use memory settings on PG - min 1x "work_mem" but with complicated queries more "work_mem" segments.

Comment: ehh there is nothing like min 1xwork_mem, if on connection user runs only SELECT 1; no work_mem will be used... and that's completely different thing from connection memory which normally costs postgres 2-4MB.